# Warning disappear in set time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I wish to display warning and make it disappear with nice effect (going slowly to transparent and disappear in the end) in set amount of time, could you help me what technology should I use! I guess AJAX or javaScript can do that?

Warning I'm using now is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function enableWarning_feedbackSent()
{
    var warn = $('<label style="color:Red;font-size:12px;font-family: Verdana;">Thank you for your feedback!</label>');
    $('.warning_feedback').text('').append(warn);   
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the `fadeOut` method within jQuery.

Comment: Have u visited [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/hide/) link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function enableWarning_feedbackSent()
{
    var warn = $('<label style="color:Red;font-size:12px;font-family: Verdana;">Thank you for your feedback!</label>');
    $('.warning_feedback').text('').append(warn); 
    $('.warning_feedback').find('label').fadeOut(3000);   //new line, 3000 is milliseconds, you can change this value
    return true;
}
```

You could also just change the `.text()` of `$('.warning_feedback')`, without append; and make in fade out/disapear -> add new text -> fade in/out

Comment: Thanks for your example but only thing you have to do is just remove single quotes around milliseconds!